# A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'UsePythonVersion'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed,

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

i am new to Azure DevOps and have been trying to run a simple task in azure-pipelines.yml CI pipeline.

```
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Pytest
    displayName: Pytest
    pool:
      vmImage: ($vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.8'
    - bash: pytest
    - bash: find ./tests/ -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint --jobs=2
```

However, i get the error for the task UsePythonVersion and also for Bash :

A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'UsePythonVersion'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 0, job 'Pytest', step ''.)

A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Bash'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 0, job 'Pytest', step ''.)

I tried looking for these on the Marketplace as well, but no clue.
Any leads here would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, actually the case was that Disable built-in tasks in organization Settings was enabled.
One can find it in Organizations Setting - > Pipelines -> Settings -> Tasks Restrictions -> Disable built-in tasks

Answer (score 0):

The [task's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) says:

> Prerequisites
>
> - A Microsoft-hosted agent with side-by-side versions of
>   Python installed, or a self-hosted agent with Agent.ToolsDirectory
>   configured (see FAQ).
>
> This task will fail if no Python versions are
> found in Agent.ToolsDirectory. Available Python versions on
> Microsoft-hosted agents can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#software).

Perhaps your agent does not have those prerequisites?

Comment: Thanks, actually the case was that Disable built-in tasks in organization Settings was enabled. One can find it in Organizations Setting - > Pipelines -> Settings -> Tasks Restrictions -> Disable built-in tasks

Comment: Ah, that's interesting!

Comment: Also: it'd be useful if you post that as an Answer yourself; then it's a useful reference for anybody else facing similar problems in future.

Comment: good idea Vince